# Trying to pass props to children in Vue: “Expected String with value ”[object Object]“, got Object”

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I´m trying to do a simple To-do app, and I want that when button `<b-button v-on:click="newItem" pill variant="primary">Añadir</b-button>` gets clicked, below shows what in the input is being written.

So i use v-model in the input (which is in the Parent component, `TodoList.vue`) and then the v-bind in the component (because the h6 which shows the text its in the Child component, `TodoItem.vue`)

Here´s how I have it:

```js
//TodoList.vue:

<template>
  <div class="todo-list-wrapper">
    <div class="mt-2 first-wrapper">
    <b-form-input v-model="titulo_item" placeholder="añade alguna cosa... "></b-form-input>
    <b-button v-on:click="newItem" pill variant="primary">Añadir</b-button>
    </div>
  <TodoItem v-bind:titulo_item={titulo_item} />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
export default {
    name: 'TodoList',
    components: {
        TodoItem
    },
    data () {
    return {
      titulo_item: "",
      itemEstaCreado: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      newItem: function (){
      this.itemEstaCreado = true;
    }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```js
//TodoItem.vue

<template>
  <h6 class="mb-0">{{titulo_item}}</h6>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TodoItem',
    components: {
        
    },
    props: {
     titulo_item: {
      type: String,
     }
    }
}
</script>
```

Problem is, when I write in the input, for example "apples", below it shows `{ "titulo_item": "apples" }` when obviously i just want it to show `apples` like a normal paragraph

I don´t know where exactly in the code i am passing an object, and not a simple string.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<TodoItem v-bind:titulo_item="titulo_item" />
```

This binds the prop named `titulo_item` to the value of `titulo_item` in the `TodoList` component instance.

The original code was: `titulo_item={titulo_item}`, which binds `titulo_item` to the value of `{titulo_item: titulo_item}` (using [object shorthands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)). This is why you were getting an object instead of a string.